# Fail to save large CSV from pySpark directly to AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

I am trying to save a large data frame (30k*17k) from spark on AWS EC2 to AWS S3.
I am able to save other smaller data frame but ever time try to save this large one, it gives me weird py4j error.

Codes are as following:

```
import time
import findspark
findspark.init("/home/xxx/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7")

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit

#initialize the spark session 
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("ingestion").getOrCreate()

########
def jvReadRedshift(sparkSession, #An existed spark session should be input
                   url,          #URL of redshift
                   port,         #Port number, normally 5439
                   dbname,       #Database name
                   user,         #User name
                   password,     #Password
                   query):       #Query which is in form of "select * from schema.table"

    sc = sparkSession.sparkContext
    sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "xxxx")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "xxxx")

    dt = sql_context.read \
                        .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
                        .option("jdbcdriver", "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver")\
                        .option("url", str("jdbc:redshift://"+url+":"+str(port)+"/"+dbname+"?user="+user+"&password="+password)) \
                        .option("query", query) \
                        .option("user",user)\
                        .option("password",password)\
                        .option("tempdir", "s3n://xxx/xxxx") \
                        .option("temporary_aws_access_key_id","xxxx")\
                        .option("temporary_aws_secret_access_key","xxxxx")\
                        .load()
    return dt


def ct_long_table(dt_long,
                  identifying_col = ["xx_id","x_id"],   #Support multiple columns
                  longitudinal_col='x',         #Only one column
                  cohort_col = "xx",                            #Only one column
                  cohort_val_col = "xxx"):                 #Only one column

    dt_long = dt_long.withColumn('pivot_col', 
                                       concat(col(longitudinal_col),lit('_'), col(cohort_col)))
    dt = dt_long.groupby(identifying_col).pivot("pivot_col").agg(first(cohort_val_col))

    return dt

print("Reading long table")
dt_long = jvReadRedshift(sparkSession=spark,
                         url="xxxxx",
                         port=5439,
                         dbname="xxxx",
                         user="xxx",
                         password="xxxx",
                         query="xxxxx")
print("Reading wide table")
dt_wide = jvReadRedshift(sparkSession=spark,
                         url="xxxxx",
                         port=5439,
                         dbname="xxxx",
                         user="xxxx",
                         password="xxxxx",
                         query="xxxxx")
print("Pivoting long table")
dt = ct_long_table(dt_long,
                  identifying_col = ["xx_id","x_id"],   
                  longitudinal_col='x',         
                  cohort_col = "xx",                            
                  cohort_val_col = "xxx")

print("Merging tables")
new_dt = dt_wide.join(dt, on=['xx_id', 'x_id'], how='left_outer')

start_time = time.time()
#dt_wide.coalesce(1).write.csv("ingestion/jsmc_wide.csv", header=True)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
dt_wide.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('s3n://xxx/xxx')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
dt_long.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('s3n://xxx/xxxx')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


######This does not work
start_time = time.time()
new_dt.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('s3n://xxx/xxxxx')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I can succesfully send dt_wide and dt_long to S3 as CSV.
However when I try to send the new_dt, it shows:

```
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:43489)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jvion/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 929, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
```

Comment: Have you tried saving it locally on the master node or on HDFS?

Comment: @Denis Makarenko  -I have. Saving locally also gave me similar error. However I tried to pivot a smaller table and merged them, I am able to save the smaller merged table with exactly same code.